# Get value from selected combox and put it on textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

Mabuhay!

Hi! I search this code here but unfortunately didnt get what I am looking for. Any help on this?

I got this form and have a combo box which i uses dataset so I can get the value of description on this table. And I have a textbox after that but I wanted to get the value of labor cost based on what I selected on combo box.

heres for my combobox

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_10daliriPayrollDataSet.Description' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
     this.descriptionTableAdapter.Fill(this._10daliriPayrollDataSet.Description);
 }
```

for my laborcost.Text value

```
private void description_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    laborcost.Text = description.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

I got this error;

> System.Data.DataRowView

Any help on this?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: have you looked at the other properties of your combobox like selectedtext?

Comment: `description.SelectedValue` or `description.SelectedText` should do the trick

Comment: Mabuhay! Hi! Thank, i used SelectedValue.ToString(); and it appears on my Textbox. How about showing another value from that row into another textbox?

Sample Data

Description           Laborcost       Service Charge
Plastic                  5.0                   1.0 


Got that combobox and 2 Textbox
1 Textbox is success just like what you guys suggested. Is it possible to show the service charge on the other textbox?

Its like hitting combobox on select and the 2 textbox will get the value from selected combobox?

and the value will be
Textbox1 = 5.0
Textbox2 = 1.0

Answer (score 0):

try

`description.SelectedItem.Text` this will do

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
description.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of retrieving the item text is the [GetItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

It works for any item, including the selected one. The later can be retrieved from the [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

In your case

```
laborcost.Text = description.GetItemText(description.SelectedItem);
```

Please note that `SelectedText` and `SelectedValue` properties (suggested by some commenters) have different semantics and cannot be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define DataValue member and Text Member field on your combobox. Its binding with  DataRowView.

So just add two  line after
this.descriptionTableAdapter.Fill(this._10daliriPayrollDataSet.Description);